# database or flat file structure behind autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I'm looking at using either jQuery autocomplete or Twitter's typeahead to look up a list of users on my site...

Obviously the data is best parsed through with json, but what is the best way to serve this data? I have a php/mysql setup, but if I have thousands of users, ideally I don't want to submit a new query for every letter typed in the input box, so would it be more efficient to use static json files instead of generating it from the database or is there something else I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: That depends on many factors. How up-to-date does the data need to be? Is it really a performance problem? Could a memcache solution be even better? Are you using a CDN or not?

Comment: And what would be the size of that static file over all.

Comment: ideally it would need to be no more than an hour behind... not using a cdn. Could have up to hundreds of thousands of users

Comment: And how much data are we talking about? Even if you put everything into one file, it's still feasible to download it into the client? Or is it so prohibitively large that you require a database to filter it?

Comment: large traffic and large data so needs to be best of both fast and up to date

Comment: Then perhaps you want a memcache or maybe a caching proxy like nginx in front of your web API.